# delete common dictionaries in list based on a value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How would I delete all corresponding dictionaries in a list of dictionaries based on one of the dictionaries having a character in it.

```
data = [
       { 'x' : 'a', 'y' : '1' },
       { 'x' : 'a', 'y' : '1/1' },
       { 'x' : 'a', 'y' : '2' },
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
    ]
```

For example, how would I delete all of the `x = a` due to one of the `y` in the `x=a` having a `/` in it?  Based on the example data above, here is where I would like to get to:

```
cleaneddata = [
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
       { 'x' : 'b', 'y' : '1' },
    ]
```

I have a CSV with a dump of many network devices (imported via DictReader). Unfortunately each device name is repeated in "x". The modules are in "y". I'm inevitably trying to reconstruct the devices by grouping them and listing all the modules for each device. Within the CSV data there is devices I don't care about. These can be identified by certain characteristics in "y". Therefore my thought is to identify and clean them out of the data up front. I'd be open to a more optimal method of cleaning the data.

Comment: so if y has anything other than an integer?

Comment: yes, within the data there is strings too

Answer (score 2):

Basically

```
for p in data:
    if '/' in p['y']:
        cleaneddata = [q for q in data if q['x'] != p['x']]
        break
```

Based on your update, I'd suggest that you create a dict like `device->module` from CSV:

```
from collections import defaultdict

devices = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    devices[row['x']].append(row['y'])
```

And then remove devices you're not interested in:

```
clean_devices = {}
for dev, modules in devices.items():
    if all('/' not in m for m in modules):
        clean_devices[dev] = modules
```

If your `rows` have more data than just modules, you can consider a dict of lists of dicts (eek:):

```
devices = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    devices[row['x']].append(row)
```

and then:

```
clean_devices = {}
for dev, row in devices.items():
    if all('/' not in m for m in row['modules']):
        clean_devices[dev] = row
```

Comment: Sure... I have a CSV with a dump of many network devices (imported via DictReader).  Unfortunately each device name is repeated in "x".  The modules are in "y".  I'm inevitably trying to reconstruct the devices by grouping them and listing all the modules for each device.  Within the CSV data there is devices I don't care about.  These can be identified by certain characteristics in "y".  Therefore my thought is to identify and clean them out of the data up front. I'd be open to a more optimal method of cleaning the data.  -Thx

Comment: @pythoonatic: Thanks for clarification. I edited it in for other's benefit.

Comment: Thank you.  you answered my question.  I guess i realize though now, I oversimplified my question.  I also have other columns that Im pulling in with the csv that I need to carry with the module.  So say "z" key that has module description.  Don't need to take any action with that, just need to carry the info along so I can display it later later.  Any chance you can update to support this?

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
x_excludes = set([d["x"] for d in data if not d["y"].isdigit()])
new_list = [d for d in data if d["x"] not in x_excludes]
print new_list
```

this first creates a list of bad X values based on some condition (in this case if there are any non-digit characters in Y)

then it just filters out any data where X exists in our earlier calculated set of bad X values